# Why doesn't the CSV file in my applet work?

Tags: java, html, csv, applet

I created an applet that requires a CSV file for information.  The way the applet works, is that there is a text field in which you type in your zip code, then you press a button. That causes the program to parse through the CSV file which contains a latitude and longitude, then display the latitude and longitude on a `JLabel` in the applet.

When I created it, I debugged it and tested it, so I know it works on my desktop (when running in eclipse).  The problem is when I put in on the web, it displays but can't do anything, meaning it is just an applet with a text field and a button, but when you press the button, nothing happens. I know that it is not my `ActionListener`, because it works on the desktop, but I must be doing something wrong with the HTML of it. The name of the CSV file is `zips.csv`.  The name of the main class is `main.class` (or `main.java`) and the action listener is `myActionListener.class` (or `myActionListener.java`).

Here is the HTML that I am using for it right now:

```
<applet archive="sites/default/files/myApplet.jar" code="main.class" width="500" height="200"> 
</applet>
```

> ### Revision:
>
> **Romething else that someone recommended to me was to create a php script that will parse the csv file, and than have that return a value to the java applet. My knowledge of PHP ls limited, so I was wonder if someone could tell me how I could go about doing this, or telling me where I can learn how to do this.**

Comment: Are you checking the Java Console for output?  Are you attempting to load the ZIP as a Zip **File**?  Do you have an URL where we can see the applet fail?

Comment: the CSV file is loaded inside the class and is packaged into the Jar file. it uses
CsvReader products = new CsvReader("zips.csv");
in order to load it

Comment: What about the answers to questions 1 & 3?  I don't like having to ask twice.

Comment: unfortunately, because the client wants anonymity, I can't give out the URL in which the site is being created. what do you mean by the java console? if you are talking about the one in eclipse, it works perfectly, but as you said, it's different on the desktop than online.

Comment: *"what do you mean by the java console? if you are talking about the one in eclipse,.."* Ask yourself - why would I be prompting you about a console in an environment where it *works*?  No, I mean the **Java** console - not an Eclipse console.  1) Open the [Java Control Panel](http://pscode.org/player.jnlp) 2) Close the cache viewer 3) Go to the Advanced tab 4) Expand the "Java console" leaf 5) Select "Show console" 6) Refresh the page or restart the browser.

Answer (score 2):

```
CsvReader products = new CsvReader("zips.csv");
```

My crystal ball tells me that `CsvReader` presumes the `String` to represent a `File` object.  It might also have another constructor that accepts an `URL`.

A sand-boxed applet cannot access `File` objects, and a trusted applet can only access `File` objects on the computer of the end user.  That is useless to this applet.  If the API has a constructor that accepts an `URL`, that is the one to use here.  Something like:

```
URL url = this.getClass().getResource("zips.csv");
//CsvReader products = new CsvReader(url);
InputStream is = url.openStream();
CsvReader products = new CsvReader(is);
```

A constructor that accepts an `InputStream` is even more versatile, and only a line longer.

If the `CsvReader` accepts neither of `URL` or `InputStream`, I suggest you find another API.  One that was *not* written by amateurs.

Comment: ok, so I'm getting a `Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-14" java.security.AccessControlException: access denied (java.io.FilePermission zips.csv read)`

Comment: I would expect to see the ACE for the `String` constructor, but it would not do that for an `InputStream` or an `URL` coming from a resource on the applet's run-time class-path.  BTW - glad you found the (Java) console.  An IDE would typically run applets with no security manager, but once it is in a browser, the security manager is provide 'for free'.  ;)